# Fixed bottom not working with parent having overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm wanting to have a sticky footer nav type of thing on the bottom of my first `col-6` (within, not outside) the div. Problem is, it has `overflow` which seems to be preventing me from getting it to work. Closest I got to was it starting in the correct position, then it scrolled due to the overflow. I'm scratching my head a bit here.

PS- Sorry there's a lot of code, I added a lot of placeholders to force the `overflow` so it's more authentic.

```css
.b-wrapper {
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  max-width: 1024px;
  max-height: 768px;
}
.booking-item {
  padding: 30px 15px 30px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
  min-height: 30px;
}
.tts {
  max-height: 650px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}


.book_apt {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="container" style="height:100vh;">
  <div class="row justify-content-center h-100">
    <div class="col-12 my-auto mx-auto">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body p-0">

          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-6 pr-0 tts">


              <div class="book_apt">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Book Service</a>
              </div>


<!-- Added a lot to force the overflow -->
              <div class="booking-item" id="booking">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="form-check my-auto">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="test-check">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6 my-auto">
                    <h6 class="mb-0 pb-0">Swedish Massage</h6>
                    <small><i>30min</i></small>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 my-auto text-right">
                    GBP £38
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              
                                <div class="booking-item" id="booking">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-2">
                                            <div class="form-check my-auto">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="test-check">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-6 my-auto">
                                            <h6 class="mb-0 pb-0">Swedish Massage</h6>
                                            <small><i>30min</i></small>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-4 my-auto text-right">
                                            GBP £38
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="booking-item" id="booking">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-2">
                                            <div class="form-check my-auto">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="test-check">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-6 my-auto">
                                            <h6 class="mb-0 pb-0">Swedish Massage</h6>
                                            <small><i>30min</i></small>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-4 my-auto text-right">
                                            GBP £38
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="booking-item" id="booking">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-2">
                                            <div class="form-check my-auto">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="test-check">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-6 my-auto">
                                            <h6 class="mb-0 pb-0">Swedish Massage</h6>
                                            <small><i>30min</i></small>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-4 my-auto text-right">
                                            GBP £38
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                                

              <div class="booking-item" id="booking">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="form-check my-auto">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="test-check">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6 my-auto">
                    <h6 class="mb-0 pb-0">Swedish Massage</h6>
                    <small><i>30min</i></small>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 my-auto text-right">
                    GBP £38
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="booking-item" id="booking">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="form-check my-auto">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="test-check">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6 my-auto">
                    <h6 class="mb-0 pb-0">Swedish Massage</h6>
                    <small><i>30min</i></small>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 my-auto text-right">
                    GBP £38
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>



              <div class="booking-item" id="booking">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="form-check my-auto">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="test-check">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6 my-auto">
                    Massage Therapy (60 minutes)
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 my-auto text-right">
                    GBP £38
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-6">

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `position: fixed;` to `position: sticky;` and move `book_apt` to the bottom of your `col-6`.
This should do the trick.

```css
.b-wrapper {
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  max-width: 1024px;
  max-height: 768px;
}
.booking-item {
  padding: 30px 15px 30px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
  min-height: 30px;
}
.tts {
  max-height: 650px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}


.book_apt {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container" style="height:100vh;">
  <div class="row justify-content-center h-100">
    <div class="col-12 my-auto mx-auto">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body p-0">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 pr-0 tts">
              <!-- Added a lot to force the overflow -->
              <div class="booking-item" id="booking">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="form-check my-auto">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="test-check">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6 my-auto">
                    <h6 class="mb-0 pb-0">Swedish Massage</h6>
                    <small><i>30min</i></small>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 my-auto text-right">
                    GBP £38
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="booking-item" id="booking">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="form-check my-auto">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="test-check">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6 my-auto">
                    <h6 class="mb-0 pb-0">Swedish Massage</h6>
                    <small><i>30min</i></small>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 my-auto text-right">
                    GBP £38
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="booking-item" id="booking">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="form-check my-auto">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="test-check">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6 my-auto">
                    <h6 class="mb-0 pb-0">Swedish Massage</h6>
                    <small><i>30min</i></small>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 my-auto text-right">
                    GBP £38
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="booking-item" id="booking">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="form-check my-auto">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="test-check">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6 my-auto">
                    <h6 class="mb-0 pb-0">Swedish Massage</h6>
                    <small><i>30min</i></small>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 my-auto text-right">
                    GBP £38
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>                                
              <div class="booking-item" id="booking">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="form-check my-auto">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="test-check">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6 my-auto">
                    <h6 class="mb-0 pb-0">Swedish Massage</h6>
                    <small><i>30min</i></small>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 my-auto text-right">
                    GBP £38
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="booking-item" id="booking">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="form-check my-auto">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="test-check">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6 my-auto">
                    <h6 class="mb-0 pb-0">Swedish Massage</h6>
                    <small><i>30min</i></small>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 my-auto text-right">
                    GBP £38
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="booking-item" id="booking">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="form-check my-auto">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="test-check">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6 my-auto">
                    <h6 class="mb-0 pb-0">Swedish Massage</h6>
                    <small><i>30min</i></small>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 my-auto text-right">
                    GBP £38
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="book_apt">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Book Service</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.book_apt {
    background-color: #ddd;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 2em;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 8%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 58%;
    z-index: 1000;
    }
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation of how this solves the problem please? This will make your answer more understandable and useful to the OP, and to anyone else with the same problem in the future.